# Command inscribed in command

Tags: macros

May I know if there's a way to use a defined command in other commands without producing an error?
[image]
Code(the line with error is commented)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{\[log_{#1}#2\]}
\begin{document}
Expected result:$\log_{(\log_{a}{b})}{c}$

%$\log_{(\test{a}{b})}{c}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `\[` and `\]` inside the macro? These macros create a displayed equation without equation number, but they cannot be used inside inline math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `\[` and `\]` in the macro definition. Otherwise when the macro `\test` expands, it'll introduce a display math environment `\[...\]` within an in-line math environment `$...$`, which throws an error.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{\log_{#1}#2}
\begin{document}
Expected result:$\log_{(\log_{a}{b})}{c}$

$\log_{(\test{a}{b})}{c}$
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: `log` inside `\test` should be `\log`